# How to use fonts that need different fontenc together?

Tags: fonts, font-encodings

I want to use [one font](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/antykwatorunska/) for text and [another](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/artificialuncial/) for dropped capitals. Unfortunately, the font catalogue states that one needs `fontenc` parameter `T1` and the other `B1`.

Now, using `T1` kind of works.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{auncial,anttor}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\aunclfamily}

\begin{document}
  \lettrine[lines=3]{L}{orem} ipsum ...
\end{document}
```

That is both fonts are used:

[image: with T1]

However, `pdflatex` (rightfully) complains

```
./test.tex:9: LaTeX Error: Encoding scheme `B1' unknown.
```

at the lettrine command. Also, I noticed that the capital looks different when I use `\usepackage[B1]{fontenc}`:

[image: with B1]

Is it possible to properly use fonts together that need different `fontenc` settings? If so, how?

Comment: ... and then you can locally get back to B1 with `\fontencoding{B1}\selectfont`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The documentation of `auncial` says

> The Artificial Uncial font family is called `auncl`. The font is supplied in only the special bookhands `B1` encoding. Thus, to use the font in a document you need to at least have:
>
> ```
> \usepackage[B1,...]{fontenc}
> ```
>
> in the preamble.

This means that you need to declare the `B1` encoding as "secondary", announcing last the default encoding for the document:

```
\usepackage[B1,T1]{fontenc}
```

will be what you need for Western European languages.

The command `\aunclfamily` does

```
\usefont{B1}{auncl}{m}{n}
```

so you won't need anything special to go back from the B1 encoding, as the lettrine is typeset in a box, which forms a group.